# Drag a sum formula so the range will change to the following X adjacent columns?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a cell A1 that sums a range `=SUM(Weekly!F6:Q6)` and I want to drag it to the next cells so A2 would sum the next 12 columns `=SUM(Weekly!R6:AC6)`, A3 the 12 columns after it, etc...

Comment: Try a combination of OFFSET() and ROW()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following in A1.

```
=SUM(INDEX(Weekly!$6:$6, 0, (ROW(1:1)-1)*12+6):INDEX(Weekly!$6:$6, 0, (ROW(1:1)-1)*12+17))
```

Fill down as necessary.